# How to run another app from my own app? For example, I want to run Facebook when i click on a button in my app

Tags: java, android

I want to run another app from my own app, for example i want to run Facebook when i click on a button in my app.
please notice that i am new to android development

Comment: do you want to open another app in your app or do you want to open another app by using your app?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intent :

```
    Intent open_app = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("PACKAGE_NAME_ANOTHER_APP"); // like facebook package(com.facebook.katana)
   if (open_app != null) { 
    startActivity(open_app); // Please check package name is there or not because it can throw NullPointerException
   }
```

if you want to recommend any app from playstore to user on click button 
do this :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=PACKAGE_NAME_OF_APP"); like facebook (com.facebook.katana)
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Welcome bro... Happy coding 